# i write my jquery code and its working fine but it need to refresh my page to work again how to fix it without reloading my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My jquery code which is working OK but when its finish i need to refresh my page 
    so how can i work it again without refresh my page there is two images i show them with using jquery and also the way to check everything is written with jquery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fingurePrint').on('click', function() {
    $('.fingurePrintImg').css({
      'bottom': '0',
    });
    $('body').css({
      'background-color': '#e2dfdf'
    });
  });
  $('.checkbutton').on('click', function() {
    $('.fingure').css('display', 'none');
    $('.checkimg').css({
      'display': 'block',
      'margin-top': '20px'
    });
  });
  $('.closebutton').on('click', function() {
    $('.fingurePrintImg').hide(function() {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'white')
      $('.messageclose').fadeIn(100, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(4000);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
my html structure which i used it to show my contain

<body>
  <div>
    <button class="fingurePrint">
      <i class="fa fa-save" area-hidden="true"></i>
      save
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="fingurePrintImg">
    <img src="images/1.png" class="fingure">
    <img src="images/2.png" class="checkimg checkborder" width="100px">
    <div class="fingurelabel">
      <!---
<input type="checkbox">
<label class="">cant do it</label>
-->
      <div class="check">
        <button class="checkbutton">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
          check
        </button>
        <button class="closebutton">
          <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
          save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="messageclose">
    <p>
      <span><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span> Done
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Which part of the code are you trying to re-run without reloading the page?

Comment: The quick and dirty way would be to trigger the reload programatically with `document.location.reload()`

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the page? which element has to be refreshed?

Comment: This may be helpful for you:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290061/5894421

Comment: @Pratansyah when i click on the save button and my message show in i try to retry the function but it doesn't work ?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour i need to refresh it again to reload my function.

Comment: Your code is programmatically ok. You are hiding fingurprintimg but there is no more code to show it again. Just show it again after you are done e.g. as a callback function

Comment: @JagdeepSingh i try it but its not working ?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour can you tell me how to show it again as a call   back function what exactly will be written ?

Comment: finally ,$('#something').click(function() {
    location.reload();
}); i used this method and it work with me thanks for all you my friends and hope to meet again in another issues thanks